# Why are inputs still filled after reloading the page?

Tags: html, forms, input

```
<form id="form2" action="go.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user" value="" />
<input type="password" name="pass" value="" />
</form>
```

I entered some values into the inputs, and then - reload the page.
Expected the inputs being empty after reloading, because of their starting `value=""` but they're still filled.
Even after `F5` in Firefox.
Also - after navigating back and forward.
How to clear input's content after reloading the page ?

Comment: Did Firefox save the username and password for that domain? That would be my guess.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, no, Firefox did not saved anything, because submit button is not yet pressed. Just the inputs are filled, and - reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a browser feature.  Most modern browsers will save your form or login information.  Information on Firefox's form caching can be found at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-firefox-automatically-fills-in-forms.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers automatically fill form fields with data, to turn this off add the `autocomplete="off"` property to you form

Comment: Musa, I placed you code inside form's starting tag, but the form doesn't recognize it as a valid attribute.